# Line segments joining harmonic points to an arbitrary point get intersected at harmonic points too

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> If $AB$ is divided harmonically by $C,D$ and $O$ is a point not on $AB$, then prove that any transversal cuts $OA,OB,OC,OD$ in four harmonic points.

Let $OA,OB,OC,OD$ be cut by the transversal in $A',B',C',D'$ respectively. Then let $X$ be a point on $A'B'$ extended such that $ C',X$ divide $A'B'$ harmonically. So we need to prove that $X$ and $D'$ coincide. How do I proceed?

Comment: I think your approach is not that correct because letting X on A'B' and then trying to prove X is D' (which is on the outside of A'B' !) is bit hard to imagine. The correct approach in solving this problem is to apply the Menelaus theorem.

Comment: @Mick What I meant was that $X$ was on $A'B'$ extended, forgot to mention that

Comment: Could you give a hint as to where I should apply Menelaus' theorem? The lengths $OA',AA'$ etc. appear when I apply the theorem but I'm not being able to get any of $A'B',B'C',....$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Construct the line L that passes through AD and cut OB, OC at B’’ and C’’ respectively. Then try to prove that A, B’’, C’’, D’ is also a harmonic range. (This is an easier start because we have two lines with a common point, A.)

[image]

With respect to $\triangle ABB’’$, OC’’C and OD’D are two transversals that we can apply the Menelaus theorem.

Added:- If harmonic range (A, B, C, D) implies harmonic range (A, B'', C'', D'), then harmonic range (A, B'', C'', D') can further imply harmonic range (A', B', C', D'). (i.e. Harmonic range is transitive.)

Comment: This solves the question if the transversal cuts the line at $A$. What if it cuts the line at some other point?

Comment: @Helix See material just added.

Comment: Oh so you're taking $D'$ as the common point now, thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @Helix That is right. You are welcome.